# Send 'compare product' action to Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am having a products page in my site. In that I have a comparison functionality.

Now I want to send data to google analytics so that Admin can later on check which products were compared. I have captured the products I.E. on which products checkbox the user clicked and store that array of products in a jquery variable.

Now I want to send this variable in `ga` function but I am not able to do soo. Can anybody help me out with it or some other solution?

Comment: [Sending Data to Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#hits_hit_types_and_the_measurement_protocol)

Comment: Drupal 7 or Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GA Push](https://www.drupal.org/project/ga_push) module

> GA Push offers an API to enqueue informations that are sent GA
>   servers, and three submodules to track browser events (using jQuery),
>   form validation errors and log exceptions.

So, you can use the API to send an event to Google Analytics when user adds a producto to the comparison.

For example, you can use the page view function and send virtual page views for each compared product:

```
$push = array(
  'location' => '/comparision/product/' . $nid,
  'page' => 'comparison',
  'title' => 'Product ' . $product_name . ' comparison',
);

ga_push_add_pageview($push);
```

This code should called when you detect that a product is being compared.

**Disclaimer**: I'm one of the developers of this module.

Comment: $(".page-personal-loans a.compare-btn").on('click', function(event){
  var selected = []; 
$('.flag-compare-products input:checked').each(function() { 
 var parent = $(this).parent().closest('td').text().replace(/remove/g,'').replace(/compare/g,'').trim();
selected.push(parent);
  });
$push = array(
'location' => '/comparision/product/' . $nid,
  'page' => 'comparison',
  'title' => 'Product ' . selected . ' comparison',
);
ga_push_add_pageview($push);
  });.,i want to send values in selected variable to google analytics in one hit so we can calculate which product were compared

Comment: If you are using Drupal 7 you can use GA Push Browser submodule to send data to GA at certain JS events.

Comment: can we have  skype call.I am having some issues over it

Comment: No, in that way you are the only one that gets help. If we write here the questions and answers it may help other people. You may start a chat, though.